# What will be rendered/sent to ReactDOM.render() as a parament if there is a js injection with Logical Operators inside

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

so, here is the code

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

// judgmental will be true half the time.
const judgmental = Math.random() < 0.5;

const favoriteFoods = (
  <div>
    <h1>My Favorite Foods</h1>
    <ul>
      {<li>Sushi Burrito</li>}
      <li>Rhubarb Pie</li>
      {burp && <li>Not Decent</li>}
      <li>Broiled Grapefruit</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(
    favoriteFoods, 
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Me and my friend has a different opinion on what exactly will be sent to `ReactDOM.render` as a parameter when burp is `false`.

Here is mine: inside if the JS injection, when burp is false, Logical operator should return burp as in `false` so the JSX will look like

```
const favoriteFoods = (
  <div>
    <h1>My Favorite Foods</h1>
    <ul>
      {<li>Sushi Burrito</li>}
      <li>Rhubarb Pie</li>
      {burp} 
      //burp is a false, not even a JSX element 
      <li>Broiled Grapefruit</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
);
```

This will be sent to `ReactDOM.render` and the reason it is not rendered is that `{burp}` as in `{false}` is not JSX, therefore, not showing on screen.

My friend, however, see it in this way: The reason why that part of code is not running is that here I quote

> *both sides have to be true for the code to run*

because the whole logical operator evacuated `false` therefore this part of the code is invalid. He sees this as a boolean calculation. The JSX would be like

```
 const favoriteFoods = (
  <div>
    <h1>My Favorite Foods</h1>
    <ul>
      {<li>Sushi Burrito</li>}
      <li>Rhubarb Pie</li>
      //nada, this code evacated false so it will not run at all. 
      <li>Broiled Grapefruit</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
);
```

This will be sent to ReactDOM.render and the reason it is not rendered is that `{burp && <li>Not Decent</li>}` evacuated to false, this code won't run, therefore, not showing on screen.

I believe I am right but since he is a pro and I just start learning JSX two hours ago. someone help!

Comment: It will receive an interpolation that evaluates to false, which it will ignore.

Comment: @SLaks so the {burp} will be sent into .rander() but it will ignore this part of code when rendering it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. From the [React docs on conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator):

> ... in JavaScript, `true && expression` always evaluates to `expression`, and `false && expression` always evaluates to `false`.
>
> Therefore, if the condition is `true`, the element right after `&&` will appear in the output. **If it is `false`, React will ignore and skip it**.

From the [React docs on JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#booleans-null-and-undefined-are-ignored):

> `false`, `null`, `undefined`, and `true` are valid children. They simply don’t render.

Comment: So the `false` is sent into .render, and since it's not JSX so it is ignored? Great! thank you so much ^^

Comment: No. It's only ignored because it is `false`.

Comment: "since it's not JSX so it is ignored"

Not quite. It is valid JSX. The children of the <ul> node is represented as an array. When an element in the array is false, it's ignored by react. JSX is just syntax sugar. It all converts to basic JavaScript. There's no if/else logic in that conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Your interpretation is essentially correct. Here's a good reference for the technical explanation.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Comment: Thank you! because I thought if it is boolean calculate, it won't make sense when both sides is true somehow it returns <li> instead a true.